Subgroups of the multiplicative group of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$
Let $p$ be a prime and $K=\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ where $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ whenever $m\leq n$.
Let $K^{\times}$ be the multiplicative group of the field $K$.
My question is: Is it true that every proper subgroup of $K^{\times}$ is finite? If it is not, is there a classification for subgroups of $K^{\times}$?

"Then $K=\cup\mathbb{F}_p$" is incorrect. There are other algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p$.

"Is it true that every subgroup of $K^{\times}$ is finite?" Of course not: $K^{\times}$ itself is not finite.

Assuming that the union is formed inside an algebraic closure $k=\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$(or some such). You do know that $k$ also has infinite proper subfields? Such as
the union $\ell$ of the fields $\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$, where $m$ ranges over the powers of a prime $q\neq p$. Then $\ell^*$ is a proper infinite subgroup.
Another example of an infinite subgroup is (assuming $p>2$) the group $\mu_{2^\infty}$ of roots of unity of orders $2^m$, $m$ any natural number. Replace $2$ with some other prime $\neq p$, if so desired.

Thanks, I get your point. I knew there is a classification for finite subgroups of $k^{\times}$. Is there a classification for all infinite subgroups of $k^{\times}$?

I'm afraid I don't know. The peculiar properties are that each and every element has finite order, and that every finite subgroup is cyclic. Those suggest that some kind of a classification should be possible. The situation is kind of dual to profinite groups.

Thanks for your answer!

The subfields of $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$  are in $1-1$ correspondence with supernatural numbers. Since every field consists of its multiplicative group and $0$, we get a big supply of subgroups of   $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}^{\times}$.
I think that in fact the group of invertibles of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ ( being a divisible group, with no $p$ torsion, and every finite subgroup being cyclic) is isomorphic to $\oplus_{q\ne p} \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{q}]/\mathbb{Z}$. There is a $1-1$ correspondence between its subgroups and supernatural numbers relatively prime to $p$ ( they describe how large the denominators in the $q$ components can get).

By mentioning $\mathbb{F}p^\times$, do you really mean $\overline{\mathbb{F}p}^\times$? Why this group is isomorphic to $\oplus{q\neq p}\mathbb{Z}[1/q]/\mathbb{Z}$? Is the $q$ here any integers other than $p$? Why there is a 1-1 correspondence between the subgroups of $\oplus{q\neq p}\mathbb{Z}[1/q]/\mathbb{Z}$ and supernatural numbers relatively prime to $p$? Could you explain more or provide some references?

@user44312: Yes..... q means a prime not p, these days it would be $\ell$. I don't have a reference for the group of units, the Wikipedia article for the supernatural numbers links to a paper of Steinitz about the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, that might help.
